# ListAdapter in a ListFragment on honeycomb with compatibility api

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, listadapter

I am using the compatibility API to provide my app on Android Gingerbread and honeycomb devices. 
I built a `ListFragment` and set my own `ListAdapter` implementation to the `ListFragment`:

```
ListableAdapter adapter = new ListableAdapter(this.savedItems, (BaseActivity) this.getActivity());
this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

The `ListAdapter` implements the `getView` method like this:

```
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "building list item @ " + pos);
View v = convertView;
if (!this.savedItems.isEmpty() && (pos < this.savedItems.size())) {
  if (v == null) {
    LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) this.activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = vi.inflate(R.layout.saved_list_item, null);
  }

  Listable item = this.savedItems.get(pos);
  Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Item @ " + pos + ": " + item.getDisplayName());
  if (item != null) {
    ImageView icon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.saved_item_icon);
    TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.saved_item);
    StarField star = (StarField) v.findViewById(R.id.favorit);
    star.setEnabled(false);

    icon.setImageResource(item.getImageID());
    title.setText(item.getDisplayName());
    star.setChecked(item.isFavorit());
  }
}
// this.pos++;
return v;
}
```

On Gingerbread Devices (Samsung Galaxy S2) this works very fine. My list is populated as I expected. On my GalaxyTab 10.1 (Android 3.1) the Parameter `pos` is in every call `0` so I just have one list item.

Does any one know why the `ListFragment` calls the `getView` with this strange parameters?

Answer (score 0):

did you try not to cast the Activity to BaseActivity?
What happens if you use getActivity() instead.

In which part of the Fragment lifecycle do you setup the adapter?

Best wishes,
Tim

Comment: The BaseActivity is my own implementation, which extends from FragmentActivity. It just provides my Activities with some common features.
I setup the adapter in the `onResume` method.

Comment: Please try to setup the Adapter in onActivityCreated. Best wishes, Tim